# SSRS - Executing report when parameter is NULL

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I'm creating a report in SSRS using a stored procedure. My report is simple, basically pulls basic information of a client in different programs.

In my stored-procedure I have two parameters: `@StartDate DATETIME` and `@VendorId INT = NULL`.

I'm setting `@Vendorid` to `NULL` because I would like to get all clients in every program.

I have two options in my sproc:

```
IF (@VendorID > 0) --Select Program
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @Report
    SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE VendorId = @VendorId
END

IF (@VendorID IS NULL) --All Programs
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @Report
    SELECT * FROM table1
END
```

This report gives me the flexibility to get clients from different programs from the day they were enrolled. Hence, if I want to get all clients in every program I simply execute the sproc with the `@StartDate` parameter. I would like to do the same in SSRS. I just can't figure how to set the `@vendorid` parameter function the same way in my sproc.

Any insight would be helpful!

Comment: Just pass `NULL` for `@VendorID` and make `@VendorID` have a default value of `NULL`.

Comment: And you can even remove your procedural logic and stick to set based with `SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE @VendorId is null OR VendorId = @VendorId`

Comment: Also best practice is to select specific column names (not *), and to list the columns you are inserting (rather than assuming all in the correct order).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AS you know generally in SSRS you can have parameters as Query string or selected value
so 
Just add

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE  @VendorId=-1 OR VendorId = @VendorId
```

To specify a custom default value here -1
Switch to Design view.

In the Report Data pane, right-click @VendorId, and then click Parameter Properties.

Click Default Values > Specify values > Add. A new value row is added.

In Value, type -1.

Click OK.

Preview the report.

You have drop down and you can use -1 as none selected.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/tutorial-add-a-parameter-to-your-report-report-builder?view=sql-server-ver15